# Msg 4104 The multi-part identifier "aA.Name" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a database from a client (Collation French_CI_AS), to which I add a new table.

I check and everything is ok:

```
select aA.Name from dbo.Table AA
```

I have a different database from a different client (Collation Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS), to which I add the same new table.

I check and I have the following error:

> Msg 4104 The multi-part identifier "aA.Name" could not be bound.

If I change the select into:

```
select bB.Name from dbo.Table BB
```

There is no error.

I need to understand why this happens.

I work with SQL 2017 express.

Comment: In Danish, `aa` is a special character ("a with a circle"), this is different from `aA` (or other variations). I didn't expect to also apply to aliasses, but I guess it does.

Comment: Indeed, I searched again and I found enough issues related to AA when the collation is Danish. Even the search with LIKE is not working properly. I changed the script and I'll avoid in the future this kind of alias. Thank you very much for your answer.